# Django "The view didn't return an HttpResponse object."

Tags: django, http, view, response

I have a simple view in which I'm saving a form. The code seems 'clean', but I can't get rid of the error:

> "The view didn't return an HttpResponse object."

Though I've searched on the web, I did not find a relevant indication.

```
def classroom_privacy(request,classname):
         theclass = Classroom.objects.get(classname=classname)
     if request.method == 'POST':  
       form = PrivacyClass(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
           new_obj.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('.')    
       else:
           form = PrivacyClass()     
       return render_to_response('classroom/classroom_privacy.html', {'form': form}, 
          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: The trivial question: You send a POST request?

Comment: For passerby: "Did you forget to `return` the response?"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

verify the indentation of your code

```
def classroom_privacy(request, classname):
    theclass = Classroom.objects.get(classname=classname)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PrivacyClass(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            new_obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('.') 
    else:
        form = PrivacyClass()  

    return render_to_response('classroom/classroom_privacy.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

if it is get request, render a unbound form

if it is post request and invalid form render a bound form

if it is post request and valid form redirect the page

Comment: you're right. I actually had am indentation problem ! thank you!

Comment: This is correct and all on a sudden the validation is now working

Comment: Somehow I managed to have the same indentation error in my forms.py
thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

All view functions must return some kind of HttpResponse object. There exists a code path in your function where `None` will be returned instead. This will occur when `request.method != 'POST'` and you'll simply "fall off the end" of your function (which will return `None`).

Comment: yes. you are right. my problem was more trivial yet, though i couldn't see. i had an indentation problem, and that 'else' was interpreted as being for the second if.
Thanks so much for interest! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **Django Rest framework**. Use the below code to return the **HTTP response** to resolve this issue.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def TestAPI(request):
    # some logic
    return HttpResponse('Hello')
```

**JSON** Response return example:

```
def TestAPI(request):
    your_json = [{'key1': value, 'key2': value}]
    return HttpResponse(your_json, 'application/json')
```

For more details about **HttpResponse**:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse