# Django 403 CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: django, csrf

I've encountered this issue but unfortunately still do not know how to fix it. The form renders perfectly, I enter the info and get a CSRF error. The reason given is `token missing or incorrect`.

View:

```
def eventSell(request, id):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    event = SquidEvent.objects.get(pk = id)
    listing_form = ListingForm(request.POST)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            listing_form = ListingForm(request.POST)
            if listing_form.is_valid():
                cd = listing_form.cleaned_data
                user = request.user
                item = Object(price = cd['price'], seller = user)
                item.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tixeng:index'), c)
            #print listing_form
        else:
            return render_to_response('tixeng/list.html', {'event' : event, 'form' : listing_form}, c)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('allauth.account.views.login'))
```

Here is my template:

```
<form action="{% url 'app:eventSell' event.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I think I've done everything right, I'm not sure what's causing the CSRF error. Also, in case its relevant I was following along with this as a guide:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSRF Token missing or incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089224/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)

Comment: try to take off the csrf(request) and keep only request, and what up your settings did you set the middleware for csrf

Comment: That book is ancient. Follow the documentation instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stack here [Django "The view didn't return an HttpResponse object."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085028/django-the-view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object) was able to help me sort it out. Once I added `context_instance = RequestContext(request)` to my `render_to_response` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`context_instance` is deprecated since version 1.8.
You can use:

```
return render(request, 'admin/match_main.html', RequestContext(request, locals()))
```